# Can't install qt-components-ubuntu because I'm using full release of QT 5.0.0

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

It appears that since I didn't install the beta1 version of QT5 from the ppa, I'm unable to use the Ubuntu components package.  I have the released version QT5 already and not interested in installing a beta version now.  Is there a workaround?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
qt-components-ubuntu : Depends: qtbase but it is not installable
                       Depends: qtdeclarative but it is not installable
```

The instructions to install the preview toolkit are [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/#step-get-toolkit).  I skipped the step to install QT5 because I already have a newer version straight from qt-project.org.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These instructions were tested on Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 12.10 both 32-bit and 64-bit.

First off we need to install some dependencies. Install these even if you already have Qt5 installed:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev libgl1-mesa-dev
```

If you haven't already, download and install the QtSDK from http://qt-project.org/downloads.

For Ubuntu 64-bit run:

```
cd ~
wget http://releases.qt-project.org/qt5/5.0.0/qt-linux-opensource-5.0.0-x86_64-offline.run
mv qt-linux-opensource-5.0.0-x86_64-offline.run qt5-installer.run
```

For Ubuntu 32-bit run:

```
cd ~
wget http://releases.qt-project.org/qt5/5.0.0/qt-linux-opensource-5.0.0-x86-offline.run
mv qt-linux-opensource-5.0.0-x86-offline.run qt5-installer.run
```

Then make it executable:

```
chmod +x qt5-installer.run
```

Now run it as root in order to install it to /opt:

```
sudo ./qt5-installer.run
```

Follow the prompts and, when asked where to install, select /opt/QtSDK.
From now on I will assume that you have it installed to that location, if you already had the Qt installed to a different location, adapt the steps in order to reflect your installation.

After installation I suggest you delete the QtCreator configuration folder as the permissions are wrong. QtCreator will recreate them when restarted.

```
cd ~/.config
sudo rm -rf QtProject
```

Now for the Qt Ubuntu Components, download the source file and unpack it:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~ui-toolkit/+archive/ppa/+files/qt-components-ubuntu_0.1.24%7Equantal1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf qt-components-ubuntu_0.1.24~quantal1.tar.gz
```

Now in order to compile and install the components we need to create some sim-links.

For Ubuntu 64-bit run:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/QtSDK/5.0.0/gcc_x64 /opt/qt5
```

For Ubuntu 32-bit run:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/QtSDK/5.0.0/gcc /opt/qt5
```

One more thing before we compile and install, we need to change two environment variables, PATH and QML_IMPORT_PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/qt5/bin
export QML_IMPORT_PATH=/opt/qt5/imports
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/qt5/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export QML_IMPORT_PATH=/opt/qt5/imports' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now we need generate a Makefile an build the Qt Ubuntu Components:

```
cd ~/trunk
qmake ubuntu-sdk.pro
make
sudo make install
```

If everything went OK, the the components should be built and installed, now we need to try it out to make sure everything went alright. I suggest you log out and the back in before doing the next steps.

- Open QtCreator, go to Tools -> Options, select the External Tools
  tab.
- For Qt Quick 1 Preview (qmlviewer), in the Executable field write: /opt/qt5/bin/qmlviewer
- For Qt Quick 2 Preview (qmlscene), in the Executable field write: /opt/qt5/bin/qmlscene.
- Click Apply and close the Options window.

Everything should be working now, one thing to keep in mind is that in order to successfully execute a QML Ubuntu Phone Application, in the .qmlproject file you need to uncomment importPaths and add "/opt/qt5/imports" to it like so:

```
Project {
    ...
    /* List of plugin directories passed to QML runtime */
        importPaths: [ "/opt/qt5/imports" ]
    ...
}
```

That's about it. For any questions comment and I'll try to get back to you. Have Fun!

Comment: Worked pretty well; after install, I did have to fix ownership of my ~/.config/QtProject folder as my user account could access the files.  The QtSDK installer had left a few files under ~/.config/QtProject with root:root ownership.

Comment: Working through the CurrencyConverter tutorial, the "import" directive checks out, and the Label element is recognized but the ItemStyle attribute isn't.  If I comment out the ItemStyle.class attribute then QtCreator is happy again.  Odd.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I haven't gotten through the tutorial yet. I've only played with individual components and edited some of their properties. But if you do figure one what the problem is I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your inputs kicsyromy. I just happened to follow below steps to resolve "import QtQuick 2.0" and other issues on executing and testing Ubuntu components on my installation.

- Untar Ubuntu components (`qt-components-ubuntu_0.1.24~quantal1.tar.gz`) under any permission directory and you will get the trunk directory like this `/home/<user>/UbuntuQt/trunk/`
- Try to override permission for trunk directory as (sometimes I happen to see error as permission denied):

  ```
  sudo chown <user-name> -R trunk/
  ```
- Set your QML_IMPORT_PATH to your `/home/<user>/UbuntuQt/trunk/modules`
- Try to execute components demo with `ubuntu-sdk.pro` with this command:

  ```
  /opt/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile ubuntu-sdk.pro
  qmlscene --fullscreen -I modules demos/PhoneComponentShowcase.qml
  ```

  or

  ```
  qmlscene -I modules demos/ComponentShowcase.qml
  ```
- To test unit converter, do create *qmlproject.user* in `/trunk/examples/`

  ```
  /opt/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile examples.pro
  qmlscene -I ../../modules unit-converter/converter.qml
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Easier way would be to add the PPA from https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-proper to the sources.list. After that a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

followed by your installation command should fix the problem.

Comment: OP mentioned that he already installed full version of Qt and not interested to install beta version from ppa

Comment: This topic is related to two other topics which refer to this one so it could be helpful for the authors of these threads.