# Ubuntu.Components QML Module

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I installed QTCreator and Ubuntu SDK as shown [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/#step-get-toolkit).
When trying to run the code sample provided [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/), QTCreator tells me it can't find the Ubuntu.Components QML Module.

**Notes**:

The build-logs says:

> file:///home/giladnaaman/Programming/Projects/CurrencyConverter/CurrencyConverter.qml:2 module "Ubuntu.Components" is not installed

But the directory `/opt/qt5/imports/Ubuntu/Components`
exists (and is full of files).

After adding `importPaths: [ "/opt/qt5/imports" ]` to the `qmlproject` file:

> QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins.
>
> QMetaType::registerType: Binary compatibility break -- Type flags for 'QPaintBufferCacheEntry'[1024] don't match. Previously registered TypeFlags(0x103), now registering TypeFlags(0x3).

Answer (score -1):

It can not work, if you install Ubuntu UI toolkit according that website.
http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/#step-get-toolkit

I reinstall Qt5 and Ubuntu UI toolkit according this website,
and problem have gone.

You must compile Ubuntu-components and then install it into Qt5.
This article tell how to do it.
[Can't install qt-components-ubuntu because I'm using full release of QT 5.0.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236012/cant-install-qt-components-ubuntu-because-im-using-full-release-of-qt-5-0-0/244708#244708)

It will work for Qt Quick1/2 UI project not for Qt Quick1/2 Applications projects.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: How do I compile Ubuntu-Component? Where can I download its source?

Comment: Hi Gilad, i posted wrong website.[link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236012/cant-install-qt-components-ubuntu-because-im-using-full-release-of-qt-5-0-0/244708#244708).This is right website. It will tell you how to download Ubuntu-components and compile it.