# Problems with QML Tool Kit Installation: "unmet dependencies: qt-components-ubuntu: ... "

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, qml, dependencies

I am following the directions on the page for Ubuntu App Development:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/

---

**Command 1**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-beta1 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qt5-meta-full && echo 'export PATH=/opt/qt5/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

**Output 1**:

```
...  
Fetched 745 kB in 3s (204 kB/s)  
Reading package lists... Done   
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
qt5-meta-full is already the newest version.  
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:  
 libtiff4 libtiffxx0c2 linux-headers-3.5.0-17 linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic  
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

**Command 2**

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qt-components-ubuntu qt-components-ubuntu-demos qt-components-ubuntu-examples qt-components-ubuntu-doc notepad-qml
```

**Output 2**

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have  
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable  
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created  
or been moved out of Incoming.  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:  

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
  qt-components-ubuntu : Depends: libqt5core5 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable  
                    Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable  
                    Depends: libqt5qml5 but it is not installable  
                    Depends: libqt5quick5 but it is not installable  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

As specified, I set the `PATH` to include `/opt/qt5/bin`. I was wondering if this issue was familiar to anyone. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Have you see that the *universe & multiverse* repositories are enabled in the `software-sources`? [This is my SS conf](http://i.imgur.com/QVI5ops.png) as reference

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/236012/114818

Comment: @Aditya: in this question OP followed instrctions without skiping steps, But in the linked question OP skipped a step because he already installed QT5 libs from qt website(obviously it is not a debian package), So the questions are diffrent

Comment: @Aditya: No it is not applicable

Comment: @Tachyons: Then, this master question dealing with Unmet Dependencies should be helpful - [How do I resolve Unmet Dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

This started happening today to my existing install as well. My guess is Canonical are changing the package dependencies either preparing for the final Qt5 release or revamping the Qt5 beta.

Keep an eye on `ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-beta1` and `ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper` as well as for updated instructions on http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/

**EDIT**: The [build log from yesterday](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/129966204/buildlog_ubuntu-quantal-amd64.qt-components-ubuntu_0.1.27~quantal1_UPLOADING.txt.gz) indicates that `'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper/ubuntu quantal main'` is being used now.

I guess we'll just have to wait for updated instructions.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I hope I'll be able to start developing soon.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and asked for help at the #ubuntu-phone irc. They came up with the solution to use the `ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper` PPA from launchpad. Therefore just add https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-proper to the `sources.list`. After that run

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

and you should be able to complete the instructions from http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/.

Comment: Better idea!  Use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper`.  It'll add to sources.list.d (which makes for easy deletion!) and handles getting the PGP keys that're needed for verification and otherwise for any/all PPAs.

Comment: I saw that the "Get the QT QML toolkit preview" section at [www.developer.ubuntu.com](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) was updated and now uses the ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper PPA!

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper/ubuntu quantal main
```

to my software sources fixed the install process.  Now to see if it all works.

Update: Not quite there yet, the qml viewers seem a little off.

```
qmlscene: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```