# unable to install the Ubuntu Toolkit

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I wanted to install the Ubuntu tool kit to get started programming, but when the install was nearly on its end it threw up the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qt-components-ubuntu : Depends: libqt5core5 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libqt5qml5 but it is not installable
                        Depends: libqt5quick5 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don’t know what the problem is and what I am able to do about it!

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/236012/114818

Comment: Why this question is duplicate? OP did'nt installed QT5 manually

Comment: IS it the same question? Or at least does the answer on that question help mine aswell?