# Are there any tutorials available which would help me learn the concepts of Mobile Development?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, monodevelop

Right now I am working on Asp & C#.net. I am also interested in Mobile App Development and want to start with Ubuntu Mobile development using C#.Net.

Are there any tutorials available which would help me learn the concepts of Mobile Development?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatly asp.net and c#.net is not supported for ubuntu phone app develepment, You should learn qml or html5 for making ubuntu phone apps

Answer (score 1):

.Net is a Windows only Framework. There are some ports for other Platforms like the .Net Micro Framework but if you would like to develop C# applications that run on windows, linux and mac you have to use the [Mono Framework](http://www.mono-project.com/). It is an open source, cross-platform, implementation compatible with Microsoft.NET. It could also be used to develop apps for mobile devices but not for the ubuntu phone OS.

If you would like to develop application for the Ubuntu phone OS, you should have a look at the [Ubuntu Developer Phone page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/). If you need help during the SDK installation process, consider the answer of kicsyromy within [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236012/cant-install-qt-components-ubuntu-because-im-using-full-release-of-qt-5-0-0).

If you would like to stay with C# you could consider developing Ubuntu desktop applications. The Ubuntu Developers page also offers a [Mono-Introduction](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/monodevelop/).

If you would like to know more about the Ubuntu Phone OS you should have a look at the answer of Luis Alvarado in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it).

Comment: I have tried to download Mono from the link you have provide but it can't download anything just shown msg as :                   Please wait
The package you requested will install shortly. and does nothing