# ctrl+R shortcut doesnt work anymore

Tags: shortcut-keys, ubuntu-touch, qt-creator

i was following the standard ubuntu touch app (currency converter), i messed things up with the showcase file, then set everything up again from scratch. Only difference being that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut doesnt work anymore, if i use the qmlviewer i get the desired output but not with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, infact i get nothing with that. 
i've posted an image of the code in Qt

[image: qt creator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an active run configuration for your project. (The arrow on the bottom left is not green)

You can change the settings under Projects->Build & Run

Comment: how can we set an active run configuration?

Comment: if you have installed the ubuntu-sdk correctly there should already be a configuration there. Please specify which version of Ubuntu you are using and make sure that you don't have interfering configurations if you have installed previous versions of the sdk and/or qt

Comment: i'm running on 12.04. i followed the answer given on [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236012/cant-install-qt-components-ubuntu-because-im-using-full-release-of-qt-5-0-0)
and i installed the QtSDK in a separate folder, i'm afraid things went wrong and i deleted the QtSDk folder. i removed and added the requisite PPAs again and re-installed Qt Creator. But, the path changes still exist, maybe that is an issue?

Comment: it would be best to install using the commands from http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/ and remove the version of qt5 in /opt/qt5/bin from PATH. The question you linked refers to the beta status of qt in the ubuntu ppa which is not the case anymore.

Comment: ok.i followed the instructions on the get-started page when i re-installed it. how do i change the value of PATH and what should i place there instead?

Comment: if you followed the instructions in the linked thread you should have 2 lines with /opt/qt5 in them at the end of your ~/.bashrc file. You can simply delete them

Comment: done. what about the changes to the importPaths? it's currently /opt/qt5/imports.
and i get an error saying that Mainview is not a type.
what would you suggest?

Comment: the default importPaths is for my install: importPaths: [ "." ,"/usr/bin","/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml" ]

Comment: mine would be "." ,"/usr/bin","/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/qml", then, but i still get an error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9382/discussion-between-djfun-and-projjol)